# how to disable a systemd service automatically?

Tags: debian, systemd, services

I would like to achieve the following with a service: I want it to start automatically at first boot, run once, and then stop and get disabled. I don't care whether it run with faults or not.

As it needs other services for the execution, `systemd` services is the way to go.

```
[Unit]
Description=Your Daemon Name
Require = otherservice.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/executable

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My questions:

- Does avoiding the `restart` keyword make sure that the script executable won't be restarted?
- How to make sure that the service gets at least stopped after the script has completed (disabling would be also good)?

Comment: would using `Type=oneshot` work for you? You would add it under `[Service]`

Comment: oneshot would run on every reboot. Replacing /path/to/executable with a script which starts the executable then disables the service perhaps comes closer to OPs requirement - but is a horrible solution. A neater solution here: https://serverfault.com/questions/148341/linux-schedule-command-to-run-once-after-reboot-runonce-equivalent

Comment: If you mean the first boot of a *new machine*, add `ConditionFirstBoot=true` to the unit. See `man systemd.unit`.

Comment: If a script should only run once, it would usually go in a package's installation scripts.  This could be `postinst` for `*.deb` or in the `%post` scriptlet for RPMs.

Comment: Otherwise, if the script generates something (like configures a file in `/etc`) then you could use something like `ConditionPathExists=`